# Remove a list item from YouTube, using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, youtube, greasemonkey

As the title explains, I am trying to create a script primarily for Greasemonkey to get rid of the first list item `</li>` which is blank in YouTube. I am not very good at JavaScript, but know the total basics.

I know I will have to do a `document.body.(etc)` but don't know exactly how to do this. The picture below shows the tree and the `</li>` tag I want to delete is highlighted. Sorry it is a tad small but just zoom in on it, and it may be a tad blurry when you zoom in but it is readable.

[image: OP's too-small image]

It would be much appreciated if you could come up with some base for the code that I could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `li` element that you wish to remove already has an `id`, i.e. `feed-pyv-container`.
So you could simply use the following code to remove it.

```
var li = document.getElementById('feed-pyv-container');
li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
```